# MixItUp with two select / dropdown fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, mixitup

I'm not advanced enough in JS to get this working fully.

I have two select fields with options:

```
    <select name="" id="filter-position">
      <option value="all">Filter by position</option>
      <option value=".instructor">Instructor</option>
      <option value=".leader">Leader</option>
      <option value=".blah">Blah</option>
      <option value=".whatever">Whatever</option>
    </select>

    <select name="" id="filter-location">
      <option value="all">Filter by position</option>
      <option value=".portland">Portland</option>
      <option value=".missoula">Missoula</option>
      <option value=".chicago">Chicago</option>
      <option value=".newyork">New York</option>
    </select>
```

The container where the filtered items live looks a little like this:

```
    <ul id="filter-container">
        <li class="mix">...</li>
        <li class="mix">...</li>
        <li class="mix">...</li>
        <li class="mix">...</li>
        <li class="mix">...</li>
        <li class="mix">...</li>
    </ul>
```

I can get each one to filter properly but not together (i.e., AND). The JS code I'm using goes like this:

```
  $(function(){
    var $positionSelect = $('#filter-position'),
        $locationSelect = $('#filter-location'),
        $container = $('#filter-container');

    $container.mixItUp({});

    $positionSelect.on('change', function(){
      $container.mixItUp('filter', this.value);
    });

    $locationSelect.on('change', function(){
      $container.mixItUp('filter', this.value);
    });
  });
```

If I filter by one select, things filter properly. If I then filter by the other, it overrides the first filter. What I want is for them to both be used.

I know there's a way to get this to work, but I'm not sure how to get that concatenated string to do the "and" logic as documented in the [Advanced Filtering](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/learn/tutorial/advanced-filtering/) section of the docs using `<select>`. Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're really close! Because of how the mixItUp API works, filters aren't additive (e.g. when you call `mixItUp.filter`, it doesn't add a new filter to what's already active). So, you just need to construct a new filter string from the values of both dropdowns whenever one of them changes. You can accomplish that like so:

```
$(function(){
    var $positionSelect = $('#filter-position'),
        $locationSelect = $('#filter-location'),
        $container = $('#filter-container');

    $container.mixItUp({});

    $('#filter-position, #filter-location').on('change', function() {

      var filterString = $positionSelect.val() + $locationSelect.val();

      $container.mixItUp('filter', filterString);
    });

  });
```

I opted to use the jQuery `.val()` over the native `.value` in this case since you're already using jQuery, and `val()` will probably be more reliable in this case. Let me know if you run into trouble.

You may also want to to change this:

```
<option value="all">Filter by position</option>
```

To this:

```
<option value="">Filter by position</option>
```

for both of your dropdown menus, otherwise you might get some weird behavior.

Comment: ah-ha! Thank you for taking the time to explain that a bit. I got real close prior to seeing your reply. This puts it all together for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use comma like..
$('#filter-location, #filter-container')
.on('change', function(){
...
;)

Comment: That doesn't achieve the desired result. The filters still cause 'OR' logic (i.e., filter by select 1 OR select 2). I need it to filter by select 1 AND select 2.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
$(function(){
    $container = $('#filter-container');

    $container.mixItUp({});

    $container.on('change','#filter-position, #filter-location', function(){
        $container.mixItUp('filter', this.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: That didn't quite work - nothing happens. I'm wondering about the $container.on('change'... bit - why would the container change?